# isAjaxRequest always return false

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

I always got the error message

404,'Model has not been saved'  with the following code

**my action controller**

```
public function actionExtend($id) {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
            $model->toDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s a',(strtotime('next month',strtotime(date('Y-01-d')))));
            if($model->save()) {
                Yii::app()->end();
            }
            else {
                throw new CHttpException(404,'Model has not been saved'); 
        }
    }
}
```

**the jquery call**

```
 $("#buttonExtend<?php echo $this->post_row;?>").click(function(e){
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('post/extend', array('id' => $data['id'])); ?>",
            });
 });
```

Why does it is not an ajax call ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: It is not about ajax request. There is something problem with your `$model->save()`.

Comment: thank you for your response  @HüseyinBABAL.   But why it does not save

Comment: model does not save usually if the model validation fails.. instead of an exception use print_r($model->getErrors()) to get the model errors

Comment: @sanfisa you need to update question as problem on saveing part. And give detail about logs or error

Comment: with alert check if your code goes into if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {alert('i am here.');}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the response, it missed a }   and the function always go to the else part of the if